# Is there any diff between these opions in behaviour?

Tags: vimrc

Actually I set these options in my vimrc:

```
set tabstop=4
set expandtab
```

But everywhere I saw (esp in [vim.wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Example_vimrc)) they set different tab option as mine.
like:

```
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
```

And I am confused, Are they same in function?
Is there any difference between these tab options in vim behaviour?
Please let me know how I can set my tab options comfortably.

Comment: Why don't you read the help section for each option? `:help 'tabstop'`, `:help 'shiftwidth'`, etc. Vim's help docs are pretty good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [article](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces) may help you clear the idea.

`set softtabstop=4` will makes backspace 4 spaces as a tab.

Comment: thanks. But I guess the expandtab do it too...

Comment: Yes, expandtab make tab as series of spaces, other options base on expandtab.